# Join 2 select statements that has nothing in common

Tags: sql-server, join, select, left-join, outer-join

I have stored procedures that perform different tasks, but I'd like to put some of them together to reduce the amount of Stored procedures created in the database. 
Many of the procedures are based on years statistics and here is an example:

```
Select 
DATENAME(MONTH, DATE_) AS Date,
 count(distinct VATNUMBER) As Count
from 
   (
    select VATNUMBER, DATE_ = min(DATE_)
    from
    ACCOUNTS a inner join CUSTTABLE b
    on a.ID= b.ID
    where ITEMNUMBER in(7055,7056,7059) AND YEAR(a.DATE_) = '2017'
    AND VATNUMBER NOT IN (
    select VATNUMBER
    from
    ACCOUNTS a inner join CUSTTABLE b
    on a.ID= b.ID
    where ITEMNUMBER in(7055,7056,7059)
    AND DATE_ < '2017-01-01'
)
group by VATNUMBER
) d
group by MONTH(DATE_), DATENAME(MONTH, DATE_)
Order by MONTH(DATE_)
```

Result for year 2017:

```
    Date     |   Count
    January  |   61
    February |   43
    March    |   23
    April    |   48
    etc....
```

And now I have same Procedure for 2018:

```
 Select 
    DATENAME(MONTH, DATE_) AS Date,
     count(distinct VATNUMBER) As Count
    from 
       (
        select VATNUMBER, DATE_ = min(DATE_)
        from
        ACCOUNTS a inner join CUSTTABLE b
        on a.ID= b.ID
        where ITEMNUMBER in(7055,7056,7059) AND YEAR(a.DATE_) = '2018'
        AND VATNUMBER NOT IN (
        select VATNUMBER
        from
        ACCOUNTS a inner join CUSTTABLE b
        on a.ID= b.ID
        where ITEMNUMBER in(7055,7056,7059)
        AND DATE_ < '2018-01-01'
    )
    group by VATNUMBER
    ) d
    group by MONTH(DATE_), DATENAME(MONTH, DATE_)
    Order by MONTH(DATE_)
```

Result for year 2018:

```
    Date     |   Count
    January  |   119
    February |   200
    March    |   112
    April    |   87
    etc....
```

What I'd like to do is to put both select statements under the same Stored procedure. A result I'd like to see is:

```
    Date 2017|   Count  | Date 2018|   Count
    January  |   61     | January  |   119
    February |   43     | February |   200
    March    |   23     | March    |   112
    April    |   48     | April    |   87
    etc....
```

Comment: Remove the year condition? And why do you want it in seperate columns? Make a YearColumn instead. Then you will Have Year,Month,Count - Much easier

Comment: Hello, im not sure what you exactly mean? Add year where? I still need that data to be presented the same way i do above

Comment: Add year as a columName. It makes no sense u want it to be seperate columns. For each year you will need to add new columns then. Year,Month,Count would be more right.

Comment: The problem is, year will return way too many data and years which are not relevant for me.

Comment: Why ? You could just say it should be for 2017 and 2018. with a where clause.